# Hadoop JobControl, second job isn't working

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to work 2 map and reduce jobs, which is second job is depended to first one. Actually, I'm trying to make count movie ratings with first mapreduce jobs and sort it with the second.
But some reasons second map and second reduce jobs aren't working.

My first Mapper

```
public class MovieRatingsMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private static final IntWritable ONE = new IntWritable(1);

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable longWritable, Text text, Context context) {
        String line = text.toString();
        String[] words = line.split("\t");

        context.write(new Text(words[1]), ONE); 
    }
}
```

First Reducer

```
    public class MovieRatingsReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context){
            //System.out.println("movie rating reducer is working");
            String word = key.toString();
            int totalCount = 0;
            for (IntWritable value : values) {
                int count = value.get();
                totalCount += count;
            }

            context.write(new Text(word), new IntWritable(totalCount));
        }
    }
```

Second Mapper

```
public class MovieRatingsSortMapper extends Mapper<Text, Text, IntWritable, Text> {

    IntWritable frequency = new IntWritable();

    @Override
    public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) {

        System.out.println("Movie Rating sort Mapper is working");

        int newVal = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        frequency.set(newVal);

        context.write(frequency, key);
    }
}
```

Second Reducer

```
public class MovieRatingsSortReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {

    Text word = new Text();

    @Override
    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) {

        System.out.println("movie rating sort reducer is working");

        for(Text value : values) {
            word.set(value);
            context.write(key, word);
        }
    }
}
```

And Driver, Main method

```
public class MovireRatingsSortDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Path inputDirPath = new Path("src/main/resources/input/movieratings/");
        Path outputDirPath = new Path("src/main/resources/output/movieratings/temp/");

        Path inputDirPath2 = new Path("src/main/resources/output/movieratings/temp/");
        Path outputDirPath2 = new Path("src/main/resources/output/movieratings/");

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "file:/");
        conf.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "local");
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);
        fs.delete(outputDirPath, true);
        fs.delete(outputDirPath2, true);
        fs.setWriteChecksum(false);

        JobControl jobControl = new JobControl("jobChain");
        Configuration conf1 = getConf();

        Job job1 = Job.getInstance(conf1);
        job1.setJarByClass(MovireRatingsSortDriver.class);
        job1.setJobName("MovieRatings");

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, inputDirPath);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, outputDirPath);

        job1.setMapperClass(MovieRatingsMapper.class);
        job1.setCombinerClass(MovieRatingsReducer.class);
        job1.setNumReduceTasks(1);
        job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job1.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        ControlledJob controlledJob1 = new ControlledJob(job1.getConfiguration());
        controlledJob1.setJob(job1);

        jobControl.addJob(controlledJob1);

        Configuration conf2 = getConf();

        Job job2 = Job.getInstance(conf2);
        job2.setJarByClass(MovireRatingsSortDriver.class);
        job2.setJobName("Sorter");

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, inputDirPath2);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, outputDirPath2);

        job2.setMapperClass(MovieRatingsSortMapper.class);
        job2.setReducerClass(MovieRatingsSortReducer.class);

        job2.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job2.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);     

        job2.setNumReduceTasks(1);

        ControlledJob controlledJob2 = new ControlledJob(job2.getConfiguration());
        controlledJob2.setJob(job2);

        // make job2 dependent on job1
        controlledJob2.addDependingJob(controlledJob1);

        // add the job to the job control
        jobControl.addJob(controlledJob2);

        Thread jobControlThread = new Thread(jobControl);
        jobControlThread.start();

        while (!jobControl.allFinished()){
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }

        jobControl.stop();
        return 0;



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new MovireRatingsSortDriver(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);

    }

}
```

First mapper and reducer works well and creates result file to /movieratings/temp but second mapper never starts without error or any information.

Can you give me some ideas, why second job is not working.
First I thought, in first reducer I give result as  but in second mapper I got inputs as  
I changed to  but nothing changed. Now I'm lack of idea.

Comment: as input I used MovieLens 100K Dataset from https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ u.data which is tab delimeter data in this format:
user id | item id | rating | timestamp

Comment: That is way too much code. Nobody is going to read and understand all of that. Please try to trim it down to only the relevant sections.